# Point to raster: QGIS vs ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, point, rasterization

I have an equidistant point grid (0.5m) and created a raster from it in QGIS and ArcMap, with different results:

**QGIS:**

- Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize
- Result: raster, with points in the
  top left corner of each "pixel"

**ArcMap:**

- Toolbox: Point To Raster
- Result: raster, with points centered

Which is the better approach? Can I emulate ArcMap's behavior with QGIS?

Comment: I don't think there is a 'better' here, it depends on your data. If you have an equidistant raster does it meet the requirement for XYZ raster data? If you want to make the raster centred then shift it by half a cell north/west see https://ssrebelious.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/raster-extent-modification-using-qgis/

Comment: Interesting question, and I can't find any documentation or settings for why it would be putting the points at the upper left rather than centroid. As Michael says, I'm not sure there is a better or worse, but I'd definitely be wondering why my raster cells weren't centered on the points. Easily fixable, but maybe the QGIS routine just doesn't do the shift for the points. Makes me wonder what happens going the other way (raster to points).

Comment: It feels like the difference comes from pixel-is-area vs. pixel-is-point. Some reading to start with http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc33_gtiff_pixelispoint. Can you share small samples of ArcMap and QGIS outputs?

Comment: @user30184 I think that link and a summary of the issue would make a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree because I can't know what really happens without studying the samples and perhaps not even then. Being just half-a-pixel shift this pixel-is-point vs. pixel-is-area interpretation is amazingly fuzzy.

Comment: @user30184 like this? QGIS: https://i.imgur.com/OTrm2Nn.png ; ArcMap: https://i.imgur.com/Zd63Oib.png (highlighted point is the same one).

Comment: Not exactly, I meant original files generated by QGIS and ArcMap. Gdalinfo reports from the both images would help also.